why vApplicationMallocFailedHook() doesn't call when memory exceed happens?
I am using stm32cubeIDE and FreeRTOS V10.2.1 on stm32l073 . I wrote a function to allocate memory more than it was allowed but my vApplicationMallocFailedHook() function does not get called . I seek for problem and I understood the __weak vApplicationMallocFailedHook() get called but my overwrite function does not get called .
how to change library or stm32 setting to solve this problem ?

Are you sure your version is linked in? Or maybe it is linked in but it is not actually called vApplicationMallocFailedHook (i.e. you are using C++ and forgot to extern "C"fy this function)?

I presume you defined configUSE_MALLOC_FAILED_HOOK to 1 in your project?

I am coding C++ and also I forgot to extern "C" but now I have done this however it does not changed the situation . Also I set the configUSE_MALLOC_FAILED_HOOK  at first time .   Actualy I understand the definition of vApplicationMallocFailedHook() was not provided in the FreeRTOS.h and when I put that on the file the problem solved but the same problem still exist for vApplicationStackOverflowHook() .

Also I checked the .map and I could not find my overwritted vApplicationMallocFailedHook() function , only the main vApplicationMallocFailedHook() was linked to the project .

I understood the vApplicationMallocFailedHook() definition did not build by the STM32 and after I putted in the FreeRTOS.h by my self , it solved but it is not the correct answer for all the time .
